# Visual Studio Project .. Upgrading Old to 2019 ... to get particular features

Tags: c#, migration, visual-studio-2019

How would a programmer migrate an old C# project to reasonably modern Microsoft VS 2019?

It seems I must explore moving files to sub directories to get more modern features in the IDE, in particular [Git] compatibility.

The source code compiles and executes. The original source code is from [many] years ago.

Preliminary Solution ... At least for git

I am not claiming this is useful.  I have only used git for one check in and one diff so far.

---

A new project was created for Windows Forms (WF).. Since WF was the style of the old project.  Then the whole older project was copied to the newly created project/solution folder.  That seemed to be a requirement again for git as provided by MS VS2019.  Git directories for both projects were deleted since there was [no] history.  Uninformed Delete. Version control was disconnected and reconnected with warnings by IDE. Old project added to new solution via context menu.  Eventually after some undesired behavior a check in and diff was performed.   A single diff (compare to unmodified).  Compare to unmodified is not being offered .  Commit is possible. I have my doubts and suspicions.  More  testing required.

---

Should I create a new similar project and try to put the old files in the new project?  The tags indicate CSharp.  Any smarter approaches?

Is it easy or difficult to move the location of source files within the project?
C# project display shows files such as

FormXX and FormXX.Designer.cs and FormXX.resx

style.  I assume I must preserve those relationships.

So I would like to keep the original source as much as possible.  Yet there is a Git incompatability problem asked in another question.

The source files are at the same level as the solution files.  Messages from the IDE lead me to believe that this may not be the modern style.

Comment: Open your project's .csproj file in a text editor. It's just XML so you should be able to see how to manipulate it as you like. You can do the same with the .sln file if you need to

Comment: @itsme86 am still editing the question.  Lets suppose I have to copy or move files to another directory.  So is editing the XML [easier and less time consuming] than attempting to let actions in the IDE move files locations?

Comment: You can do it either way. I've found that it's sometimes necessary to manually edit the .csproj file, but you can try to do what you can in the IDE. Also, to your question about source files at the same level as the solution file, My solutions are structured such that the solution file is in the parent folder of the project folders. So like MyProjects\Project1, MyProjects\Project2, and the .sln file in MyProjects.

Comment: You might want to check out the [CsProjToVs2017](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) project on github. I've personally had great success using it to convert older projects to the "new" SDK-style .csproj format

Comment: Problem . First step. I copied 3 csharp files to subdirectory named subblah. Through VS2019 IDE I deleted these files from VS IDE. Via IDE I tried to add the files in the sub directory.  The files were copied into the current directory which is not the goal.  The files came back .. yet they are in the original directory ... not the new sub directory ... according to the IDE.